# How to set to work (and simplify) this Show / Hide with FadeIn / FadeOut?

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, css-animations, fadeout

I'm trying to build a website and I want to do something like this. I want to show three images while I scroll down the page beeing each image a 'link' to show more content that appears right after each image. I need that content to display with fade in, and when I click again it needs to fade out and disapear (display: none;). I've managed to do the fade in part, but not the fade out. It disapears without the fade effect. Also there must be only one div open at a time. Here's the code so far:

```js
$('.expand, .card__btn-close').click(function() {                       
  $('.toggleText').removeClass('fadeOut'),
  $('.toggleText').toggleClass('fadeIn'),
  $('.toggleText--two').removeClass('fadeIn'),
  $('.toggleText--two').toggleClass('fadeOut');
  $('.toggleText--three').removeClass('fadeIn'),
  $('.toggleText--three').toggleClass('fadeOut');
}); 

$('.expand--two, .card__btn-close--two').click(function() { 
  $('.toggleText').removeClass('fadeIn'),
  $('.toggleText').toggleClass('fadeOut'),
  $('.toggleText--two').removeClass('fadeOut'),
  $('.toggleText--two').toggleClass('fadeIn');
  $('.toggleText--three').removeClass('fadeIn'),
  $('.toggleText--three').toggleClass('fadeOut');
}); 
            
$('.expand--three, .card__btn-close--three').click(function() { 
  $('.toggleText').removeClass('fadeIn'),
  $('.toggleText').toggleClass('fadeOut'),
  $('.toggleText--two').removeClass('fadeIn'),
  $('.toggleText--two').toggleClass('fadeOut');
  $('.toggleText--three').removeClass('fadeOut'),
  $('.toggleText--three').toggleClass('fadeIn');
});
```

```css
.img {width:300px;height:50px;}
.toggleText.fadeIn, .toggleText--two.fadeIn, .toggleText--three.fadeIn {
          -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
          -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
          -ms-animation-name: fadeIn;
          animation-name: fadeIn;
          -moz-animation-duration: .5s;
          -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
          -ms-animation-duration: .5s;
          animation-duration: .5s;
          -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
          display:block;
        }
        
        .toggleText, .toggleText--two, .toggleText--three, .toggleText.fadeOut, .toggleText--two.fadeOut, .toggleText--three.fadeOut {
          -moz-animation-name: fadeOut;
          -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
          -ms-animation-name: fadeOut;
          animation-name: fadeOut;
            -moz-animation-duration: .5s;
          -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
          -ms-animation-duration: .5s;
          animation-duration: .5s;
        display:none;
        }
        
        @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; display: none; } 100% { opacity: 1; display: block; }}
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; display: none; } 100% { opacity: 1; display: block; }}
        @-ms-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; display: none; } 100% { opacity: 1; display: block; }}
        @-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; display: none; } 100% { opacity: 1; display: block; }}
    
        @-moz-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; display: block; }  100% { opacity: 0; display: none; }} 
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; display: block; }  100% { opacity: 0; display: none; }} 
        @-ms-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; display: block; } 100% { opacity: 0; display: none; }} 
        @-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; display: block; } 100% { opacity: 0; display: none;  }}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Project 1 -->
<section>
  <a class="expand">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://marketplaceadsonline.com/marketplace/txshe/static/images/externallinks/Shoppers.png)"></div>        
  </a>  
  <div class="toggleText">
    <div class="card__content card__btn-close" style="color: #F00">
      Extra content 1 goes here!
      Vestibulum elit libero, condimentum ac sapien quis, lobortis tincidunt eros. Integer vel sapien odio. Fusce in mauris vestibulum, consequat sapien vitae, eleifend orci. Nullam congue, libero ac auctor scelerisque, risus tellus dictum nulla, ut interdum velit neque quis nibh. Etiam nibh urna, suscipit non convallis nec, aliquam a sapien. Nullam eu sapien in neque volutpat pharetra quis sed augue. Ut elementum luctus dui vel mollis. Phasellus eget mollis nibh. Fusce commodo, nisi sit amet accumsan tincidunt, risus enim aliquam sem, a convallis elit ante vel sem. Praesent lobortis nunc et finibus tempus. Nunc non metus efficitur, iaculis sapien sit amet, tristique metus. Maecenas ut felis quis ante hendrerit tincidunt a vel turpis. Proin imperdiet est sed augue consectetur sollicitudin. Donec volutpat fermentum mi nec pulvinar. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, porta pharetra urna. Curabitur feugiat, odio at pellentesque porta, justo tortor tempus diam, a suscipit libero dolor ac tortor. 
    </div> <!-- /card content -->
  </div> <!-- /toggleText -->
</section>

<!-- Project 2 -->
<section>
  <a class="expand--two">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://marketplaceadsonline.com/marketplace/txshe/static/images/externallinks/Shoppers.png)"></div>        
  </a>  
  <div class="toggleText--two">
    <div class="card__content card__btn-close--two" style="color: #F0F">
      Extra content 2 goes here!
      Vestibulum elit libero, condimentum ac sapien quis, lobortis tincidunt eros. Integer vel sapien odio. Fusce in mauris vestibulum, consequat sapien vitae, eleifend orci. Nullam congue, libero ac auctor scelerisque, risus tellus dictum nulla, ut interdum velit neque quis nibh. Etiam nibh urna, suscipit non convallis nec, aliquam a sapien. Nullam eu sapien in neque volutpat pharetra quis sed augue. Ut elementum luctus dui vel mollis. Phasellus eget mollis nibh. Fusce commodo, nisi sit amet accumsan tincidunt, risus enim aliquam sem, a convallis elit ante vel sem. Praesent lobortis nunc et finibus tempus. Nunc non metus efficitur, iaculis sapien sit amet, tristique metus. Maecenas ut felis quis ante hendrerit tincidunt a vel turpis. Proin imperdiet est sed augue consectetur sollicitudin. Donec volutpat fermentum mi nec pulvinar. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, porta pharetra urna. Curabitur feugiat, odio at pellentesque porta, justo tortor tempus diam, a suscipit libero dolor ac tortor. 
    </div> <!-- /card content -->
  </div> <!-- /toggleText -->
</section>

<!-- Project 3 -->
<section>
  <a class="expand--three">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://marketplaceadsonline.com/marketplace/txshe/static/images/externallinks/Shoppers.png)"></div>        
  </a>  
  <div class="toggleText--three">
    <div class="card__content card__btn-close--three" style="color: #00F">
      Extra content 3 goes here!
      Vestibulum elit libero, condimentum ac sapien quis, lobortis tincidunt eros. Integer vel sapien odio. Fusce in mauris vestibulum, consequat sapien vitae, eleifend orci. Nullam congue, libero ac auctor scelerisque, risus tellus dictum nulla, ut interdum velit neque quis nibh. Etiam nibh urna, suscipit non convallis nec, aliquam a sapien. Nullam eu sapien in neque volutpat pharetra quis sed augue. Ut elementum luctus dui vel mollis. Phasellus eget mollis nibh. Fusce commodo, nisi sit amet accumsan tincidunt, risus enim aliquam sem, a convallis elit ante vel sem. Praesent lobortis nunc et finibus tempus. Nunc non metus efficitur, iaculis sapien sit amet, tristique metus. Maecenas ut felis quis ante hendrerit tincidunt a vel turpis. Proin imperdiet est sed augue consectetur sollicitudin. Donec volutpat fermentum mi nec pulvinar. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, porta pharetra urna. Curabitur feugiat, odio at pellentesque porta, justo tortor tempus diam, a suscipit libero dolor ac tortor. 
    </div> <!-- /card content -->
  </div> <!-- /toggleText -->
</section>

<!-- Dummy content -->
<section>
  <div style="padding-top:50px;color:#0FF;">Vestibulum elit libero, condimentum ac sapien quis, lobortis tincidunt eros. Integer vel sapien odio. Fusce in mauris vestibulum, consequat sapien vitae, eleifend orci. Nullam congue, libero ac auctor scelerisque, risus tellus dictum nulla, ut interdum velit neque quis nibh. Etiam nibh urna, suscipit non convallis nec, aliquam a sapien. Nullam eu sapien in neque volutpat pharetra quis sed augue. Ut elementum luctus dui vel mollis. Phasellus eget mollis nibh. Fusce commodo, nisi sit amet accumsan tincidunt, risus enim aliquam sem, a convallis elit ante vel sem. Praesent lobortis nunc et finibus tempus. Nunc non metus efficitur, iaculis sapien sit amet, tristique metus. Maecenas ut felis quis ante hendrerit tincidunt a vel turpis. Proin imperdiet est sed augue consectetur sollicitudin. Donec volutpat fermentum mi nec pulvinar. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, porta pharetra urna. Curabitur feugiat, odio at pellentesque porta, justo tortor tempus diam, a suscipit libero dolor ac tortor. </div>
</section>
```

What I need is to know how to fade out before "display: none" and if the css and javascript can be simplified. Besides this, I want the page to scroll the "Show" content to the top of the page and also scroll to the same position after we "Hide" the content.

Can any of you help?

Pedro

Comment: Have you tried SASS to clean up your CSS?  Your `removeClass`, `toggleClass` pattern isn't very clean either.  In general, you should think about generating your click handlers more programmatically rather than write repetitive, imperative code like you have.  I think you'd be better served figuring that out than how to make this approach actually work.

Comment: Is my answer below what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try chaining, functions and css shorthand properties? Is this what you wanted?

```js
function clickhandler(num){
      return (function(){
          if(num === 3){
              $('.toggleText--three').removeClass('fadeOut').toggleClass('fadeIn');
          }else{
              $('.toggleText' + ((num - 1) ? '--two' : '')).removeClass('fadeOut').toggleClass('fadeIn');
          }
      });
};

$('#s1').click(clickhandler(1)); 

$('#s2').click(clickhandler(2)); 
            
$('#s3').click(clickhandler(3));
```

```css
.img {width:300px;height:50px;}
.toggleText.fadeIn, .toggleText--two.fadeIn, .toggleText--three.fadeIn {
          -moz-animation: 1s ease-in-out forwards fadeIn;
          -webkit-animation: 1s ease-in-out forwards fadeIn;
          animation: 1s ease-in-out forwards fadeIn;
        }
        
        .toggleText, .toggleText--two, .toggleText--three, .toggleText.fadeOut, .toggleText--two.fadeOut, .toggleText--three.fadeOut {
          animation: 1s forwards fadeOut;
          -moz-animation: 1s forwards fadeOut;
          -webkit-animation: 1s forwards fadeOut;
        }
        
        @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; display: none; position: absolute;top: -9999px;left: -9999px;} 100% { opacity: 1; display: block; position: static;}}
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; display: none;position: absolute;top: -9999px;left: -9999px;} 100% { opacity: 1; display: block;position: static;  }}
        @-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; display: none;position: absolute;top: -9999px;left: -9999px;} 100% { opacity: 1; display: block; position: static; }}
    
        @-moz-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; display: block; position: static; }  100% { opacity: 0; display: none;position: absolute;top: -9999px;left: -9999px;}} 
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; display: block;position: static;  }  100% { opacity: 0; display: none;position: absolute;top: -9999px;left: -9999px;}}
        @-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; display: block; position: static; } 100% { opacity: 0; display: none;position: absolute;top: -9999px;left: -9999px; }}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Project 1 -->
<section id = "s1">
  <a class="expand">
    <div class="img" id = "img" style="background-image: url(http://marketplaceadsonline.com/marketplace/txshe/static/images/externallinks/Shoppers.png)"></div>        
  </a>  
  <div class="toggleText">
    <div class="card__content card__btn-close" style="color: #F00">
      Extra content 1 goes here!
      Vestibulum elit libero, condimentum ac sapien quis, lobortis tincidunt eros. Integer vel sapien odio. Fusce in mauris vestibulum, consequat sapien vitae, eleifend orci. Nullam congue, libero ac auctor scelerisque, risus tellus dictum nulla, ut interdum velit neque quis nibh. Etiam nibh urna, suscipit non convallis nec, aliquam a sapien. Nullam eu sapien in neque volutpat pharetra quis sed augue. Ut elementum luctus dui vel mollis. Phasellus eget mollis nibh. Fusce commodo, nisi sit amet accumsan tincidunt, risus enim aliquam sem, a convallis elit ante vel sem. Praesent lobortis nunc et finibus tempus. Nunc non metus efficitur, iaculis sapien sit amet, tristique metus. Maecenas ut felis quis ante hendrerit tincidunt a vel turpis. Proin imperdiet est sed augue consectetur sollicitudin. Donec volutpat fermentum mi nec pulvinar. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, porta pharetra urna. Curabitur feugiat, odio at pellentesque porta, justo tortor tempus diam, a suscipit libero dolor ac tortor. 
    </div> <!-- /card content -->
  </div> <!-- /toggleText -->
</section>

<!-- Project 2 -->
<section id = "s2">
  <a class="expand--two">
    <div class="img" id = "img--2" style="background-image: url(http://marketplaceadsonline.com/marketplace/txshe/static/images/externallinks/Shoppers.png)"></div>        
  </a>  
  <div class="toggleText--two">
    <div class="card__content card__btn-close--two" style="color: #F0F">
      Extra content 2 goes here!
      Vestibulum elit libero, condimentum ac sapien quis, lobortis tincidunt eros. Integer vel sapien odio. Fusce in mauris vestibulum, consequat sapien vitae, eleifend orci. Nullam congue, libero ac auctor scelerisque, risus tellus dictum nulla, ut interdum velit neque quis nibh. Etiam nibh urna, suscipit non convallis nec, aliquam a sapien. Nullam eu sapien in neque volutpat pharetra quis sed augue. Ut elementum luctus dui vel mollis. Phasellus eget mollis nibh. Fusce commodo, nisi sit amet accumsan tincidunt, risus enim aliquam sem, a convallis elit ante vel sem. Praesent lobortis nunc et finibus tempus. Nunc non metus efficitur, iaculis sapien sit amet, tristique metus. Maecenas ut felis quis ante hendrerit tincidunt a vel turpis. Proin imperdiet est sed augue consectetur sollicitudin. Donec volutpat fermentum mi nec pulvinar. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, porta pharetra urna. Curabitur feugiat, odio at pellentesque porta, justo tortor tempus diam, a suscipit libero dolor ac tortor. 
    </div> <!-- /card content -->
  </div> <!-- /toggleText -->
</section>

<!-- Project 3 -->
<section id = "s3">
  <a class="expand--three">
    <div class="img" id = "img--3" style="background-image: url(http://marketplaceadsonline.com/marketplace/txshe/static/images/externallinks/Shoppers.png)"></div>        
  </a>  
  <div class="toggleText--three">
    <div class="card__content card__btn-close--three" style="color: #00F">
      Extra content 3 goes here!
      Vestibulum elit libero, condimentum ac sapien quis, lobortis tincidunt eros. Integer vel sapien odio. Fusce in mauris vestibulum, consequat sapien vitae, eleifend orci. Nullam congue, libero ac auctor scelerisque, risus tellus dictum nulla, ut interdum velit neque quis nibh. Etiam nibh urna, suscipit non convallis nec, aliquam a sapien. Nullam eu sapien in neque volutpat pharetra quis sed augue. Ut elementum luctus dui vel mollis. Phasellus eget mollis nibh. Fusce commodo, nisi sit amet accumsan tincidunt, risus enim aliquam sem, a convallis elit ante vel sem. Praesent lobortis nunc et finibus tempus. Nunc non metus efficitur, iaculis sapien sit amet, tristique metus. Maecenas ut felis quis ante hendrerit tincidunt a vel turpis. Proin imperdiet est sed augue consectetur sollicitudin. Donec volutpat fermentum mi nec pulvinar. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, porta pharetra urna. Curabitur feugiat, odio at pellentesque porta, justo tortor tempus diam, a suscipit libero dolor ac tortor. 
    </div> <!-- /card content -->
  </div> <!-- /toggleText -->
</section>

<!-- Dummy content -->
<section>
  <div style="padding-top:50px;color:#0FF;">Vestibulum elit libero, condimentum ac sapien quis, lobortis tincidunt eros. Integer vel sapien odio. Fusce in mauris vestibulum, consequat sapien vitae, eleifend orci. Nullam congue, libero ac auctor scelerisque, risus tellus dictum nulla, ut interdum velit neque quis nibh. Etiam nibh urna, suscipit non convallis nec, aliquam a sapien. Nullam eu sapien in neque volutpat pharetra quis sed augue. Ut elementum luctus dui vel mollis. Phasellus eget mollis nibh. Fusce commodo, nisi sit amet accumsan tincidunt, risus enim aliquam sem, a convallis elit ante vel sem. Praesent lobortis nunc et finibus tempus. Nunc non metus efficitur, iaculis sapien sit amet, tristique metus. Maecenas ut felis quis ante hendrerit tincidunt a vel turpis. Proin imperdiet est sed augue consectetur sollicitudin. Donec volutpat fermentum mi nec pulvinar. Duis et pellentesque ipsum, porta pharetra urna. Curabitur feugiat, odio at pellentesque porta, justo tortor tempus diam, a suscipit libero dolor ac tortor. </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Well @programmer5000 you managed to simplify my css and js but it's not complete yet. If you check my snippet, there's no empty region between images, because I want to "display:none;" after fade out, and also, I want only one section visible at a time: If you check my snippet again you can see that if you click on 'image 1' and then click on 'image 2', extra content of 'image 1' hides and you only see the content of 'image 2'.